# AWS CLI execute a lambda function issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cli

I'm trying to invoke a lambda function from my AWS CLI in windows 10. I've done previously a configuration of my client thru **AWS configure**.

The command used is:

```
aws lambda invoke \
    --function-name arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:111111111:function:xxx \
    --invocation-type RequestResponse
```

but my system is returning an error `aws: error: too few arguments`, as shown below:

[image]

Could you guys guide me to succeed in this execution?

thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like you need to provide an outfile. So re-run it as follows:

```
aws lambda invoke \
    --function-name arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:111111111:function:xxx \
    --invocation-type RequestResponse \
    outfile.txt
```

Comment: where is stocked the file outfile.txt?  do you know? thanks

Comment: It's written to the current working directory, unless you specify an explicit path such as /tmp/outfile.txt.

Comment: You are a lifesaver... I was busting my head trying to find an answer for  `runtime.ImportModuleError cannot find module 'app'` when I tried to test my lambda locally - this is probably due to my old windows 8 and docker toolbox

Answer (score 16):

In addition to @jarmod's answer:
You can use `-` if want to send output directly to stdout:

`aws lambda invoke --function-name my_function --invocation-type RequestResponse --log-type Tail - | grep "LogResult"| awk -F'"' '{print $4}' | base64 --decode`

or if you have [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

`aws lambda invoke --function-name my_function --invocation-type RequestResponse --log-type Tail - | jq '.LogResult' -r | base64 --decode`

Comment: I am using this code on Mac-os, but it creates a file in the current directory. The name is of the file is just a dash `-`. The content of the file are`{}`. I have to manually delete it each time I run the macro. Specifically, my line of code is this `AWS_PAGER="" aws lambda invoke --function-name paypal_ipn --invocation-type RequestResponse --payload fileb://"$tmp_dir"/invoke-payload.json --log-type Tail - | grep "LogResult"| awk -F'"' '{print $4}' | base64 --decode`

Comment: Also, I do not seem to be able to set an `outputfile.txt` (like in @jarmod 's answer), or otherwise print out the output of the function using your code.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are integrating with Jenkins(Windows) and dont want to use Lambda plugin. Lambda plugin is somehow not taking credentials I set in jenkins binding.

Prepare payload first. I have taken parameters from user.

```
@echo off
@echo {> payload.json
@echo  "type": "RequestType",>> payload.json
@echo  "siteCode": "%SiteCode%",>> payload.json
@echo  "siteDesc": "%SiteDesc%",>> payload.json
@echo }>> payload.json
```

Invoke lambda using aws cli.

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name "FuntionName" --invocation-type RequestResponse --region us-zone-id --log-type Tail --payload file://payload.json response.json
```

You can print response using type command.

```
type response.json
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS CLI version details

```
aws-cli/2.1.13 Python/3.7.9 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off
```

> Invoke Lambda cmd, Payload needs to be Base64 encoded (https://www.base64decode.org/), you can also install plugin if needed

```
aws configure // If applicable perform the aws configure
aws lambda invoke --function-name test_details:DEV  --payload #yHw response_test.json
```

success response

```
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ExecutedVersion": "18"
}
```

> The response_test.json should be generated under same path.
> Ref document https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html